# meta-robots in auth.php which is included in login.php

Tags: php, html, meta-tags, google-search, noindex

If I put

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
```

in `auth.php` and include `auth.php` inside `login.php` page, the `login.php` page will not appear on Google or only `auth.php` won't appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines have no insight into your PHP files. The only thing that matters is which HTML gets generated for which URL.

Every HTML document that has

1. your `meta`-`robots` element
2. in the `head` element¹

conveys that `noindex` and `nofollow` should apply for it. But note that this could be overwritten by the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag` and/or by additional `meta`-`robots` elements in the same document.

---

¹ If the `meta`-`robots` element is somewhere else than in the `head` element, it’s invalid, and it might not work.

Comment: So currently my head element does not contain anything about meta robots, so it will not appear in google when someone searches?

Comment: @JohnWiky: It may get indexed in search engines if you don’t disallow it with `meta`-`robots` (or `X-Robots-Tag`).